# Quickest way to locate nearest unit on map?

Tags: starcraft-2

In the heat of battle I tend to lose track of where my probes are or where the nearest probe is.  Is there a shortcut or a quick way to locate specific units on the map in case I lose them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lost units in general? No. Probes? Sometimes. Any time a worker (probe, drone, scv) is just sitting around doing nothing, he is considered an "idle worker", and the logo of the worker appears in the bottom left of the view area, with a number telling you how many idle workers you have. Clicking on it (or pressing F1), will cycle through them.

If there's a specific unit you keep losing, Tzenes's answer describes how to put a unit in a control group.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but it sounds like control groups would solve this problem.

Control groups are groups of units which you can specify to be selected by a single key.  To create a control group select a group of units and hold <kbd>control</kbd> and then press the <kbd>1</kbd> key.  This will bind those units to group 1.  You can now reselect them by pressing the <kbd>1</kbd> key.  To try this, select some other unit then press <kbd>1</kbd>.

You can rebind control group 1 by selecting some other units and again holding control and pressing the <kbd>1</kbd> key.  This will overwrite whatever was in control group 1 with the currently selected units.

To add a unit to a control group select the unit to add and hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and press <kbd>1</kbd>.  This will add the selected units into control 1 while preserving the current units in that control group, effectively merging them.

In addition to control group 1, you can also use control groups 2-9 and 0 by replacing the <kbd>1</kbd> key in the example with the key number of your choice.  You may only use number keys to do this.

Comment: Thanks I knew about this feature.  What I was wondering if there is a way to just say "Give me the nearest probe" regardless of wherethere I have saved it in a control group before hand.  What happens some times is i'm building things and I might forget to asign it to a control group, or I have scattered units in different groups.  There are times that I dont want to go looking through all of my groups if i'm looking for a SPECIFIC unit i know I have i just may have forgotten where exactly it is.  So it would be nice to press something that will give me the nearest probe or zealot etc..

Comment: I don't have the rep to edit posts yet so I'll just make a suggestion: when talking about keyboard commands mark the keys with kbd. i.e. Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, which doesn't apply the same formatting in a comment as it does in a question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your question: No. Unless you use hotkeys or the idle worker icon

If you are talking about probes though, the truth is, you don't need a special probe for just building structures. So there's no real need to be able to find where you left the probe in the heat of battle.

Let's say you want to build a pylon. Here's what I would recommend:

1. Hotkey your Nexus
2. Double tap your Nexus hotkey to move the screen toward your mineral patches
3. Select a probe that is gathering minerals
4. Issue the command to build a Pylon
5. After the command is issued, Hold SHIFT and right-click back on to the mineral patch.

Results: The probe builds the pylon, and then goes right back to gathering minerals. Whenever you need another pylon, gateway, etc... repeat steps 2-5