# How to best manage Protoss Observers in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

In [THIS](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3922/quickest-way-to-locate-nearest-unit-on-map/3961) question you guys answered how I can best locate/manage probes, but I forgot to ask about observers.  So I am making a new question since the last one was already answered.

Normally when I make a bunch of observers I can put them into a hot-key so that I don't lose them.

But there are times that I forget to assign a hot-key, and I also set the observer to follow one of my units.

While i'm busy with something else at another part of the map, the unit i made the observer follow may have gotten killed in action, leaving the observer wandering around.

Later, I get into a stiuation that I really need an observer, pronto, knowing that I have some scattered around the map.

Is there a way I can manage observers so that I can locate them quickly when needed?  Because right now i'm left scrolling around the map looking for one that I can use.

Comment: @Grace, I believe in the first syllable

Comment: @Juan You are correct, PRO-toss

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the general area your observer is in but are having trouble spotting it quickly, try holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. This will make its health and shield bars visible and might help you pick it out (unless it's hovering directly over a large group of ground units, or something).

Comment: In addition, you can use the left and right bracket buttons <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> to toggle your own units and enemy units health bars. this can make it easier to find your own units among a sea of enemy units.

Answer (score 5):

If the observer is just wondering around, it should be easy to pick it up in the minimap - it will be the only friendly dot in the middle of nowhere, not to mention it will give you vision of everything around.

If, however, it was forgotten next to other friendly forces / buildings, I see no easy way to locate it unless you remember where it was or you notice an unusual field of vision (too large / can see up cliffs). If you only remember the *general* area where it used to be, you can go there and drag the mouse to select an area, in case it's hiding over a building or something - this will show it in the selected unit list.

Finally - though this is something not really applicable when you're desperately looking for an observer - is that you can bring *another* observer to the area and then double-click it, that will select all the observers around including the missing one.

So I guess my best tip for you is to not lose them :) keep an emergency observer in a hot-key, it may save you later.

Answer (score 3):

First of all - make a habit to bind all your obs to one button. You can go to specific one by selecting and click on portrait (an option in 'game' settings 'smart camera pan').
If you definitely know that there is observer on current screen - box all units and find obs in group by icon.